# Google login is not working on Flutter Web

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebase-hosting

My google login is working on this firebase URL
https://amuzi-5f9d4.firebaseapp.com/#/

and files are hosted on the firebase hosting
also I've added a custom domain on the firebase hosting whose URL is amuzi.in also the domain has been connected successfully

but the google login is not working on that domain.

Apart from this I've also added amuzi.in inside of Authorized JavaScript origins  and Authorized redirect URIs in GCP[image]

[image: I've saved this for more than 24 hours]

[image: Domain Connected Successfully]